# recursion limit error with impl Fn(T) -> R

Tags: recursion, rust

I have the following code that does not compile:

```
pub enum CommandBuffer<T> {
    Sequential(Vec<CommandBuffer<T>>),
    Parallel(Vec<CommandBuffer<T>>),
    Single(Box<T>),
}

impl<T> CommandBuffer<T> {
    pub fn map_into<R>(self, mapping_fn: impl Fn(T) -> R) -> CommandBuffer<R> {
        let mapping_fn = &mapping_fn;
        match self {
            Sequential(v) => Sequential(v.into_iter().map(|c| c.map_into(mapping_fn)).collect()),
            Parallel(v) => Parallel(v.into_iter().map(|c| c.map_into(mapping_fn)).collect()),
            Single(box x) => Single(Box::new(mapping_fn(x))),
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error message:

```
error: reached the recursion limit while instantiating `CommandBuffer::<VisualCommand>::map_into::<CommandOrTask, [closure@CommandBuffer<...>::map_into<..., ...>::{closure#1}::{closure#0}]>`
```

What changes can I make to fix this issue?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue, but it's probably from using `box_patterns`. You don't need to use `Box` at all here, just do `Single(T)` https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ecb83031772c12c8f66f860f4140963

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you invoke the function with `mapping_fn` as type `F`, the compiler has to generate code for:

```
map_into(self, mapping_fn: F) -> CommandBuffer<_>
```

Within `map_into`, you pass a `&F` into a recursive call if `self` is `Sequential` or `Parallel`. But mind you, the value of `self` is a runtime value, so the compiler has to generate code for it regardless:

```
map_into(self, mapping_fn: &F) -> CommandBuffer<_>
```

If you follow the same idea a few more times, you'll see the compiler has to generate an infinite number of functions:

```
map_into(self, mapping_fn: &&F) -> CommandBuffer<_>
map_into(self, mapping_fn: &&&F) -> CommandBuffer<_>
map_into(self, mapping_fn: &&&&F) -> CommandBuffer<_>
map_into(self, mapping_fn: &&&&&F) -> CommandBuffer<_>
// ... snip ...
```

A solution could be to use dynamic dispatch (via `dyn Fn`), but that may have a performance hit. Or you could restrict `impl Fn` is `Copy` or `Clone`, but that may disallow some closures. In this case, you can make a helper function that uses a single reference and thus avoids creating new `impl Fn` types:

```
impl<T> CommandBuffer<T> {
    pub fn map_into<R>(self, mapping_fn: impl Fn(T) -> R) -> CommandBuffer<R> {

        fn helper<T, R>(buff: CommandBuffer<T>, mapping_fn: &impl Fn(T) -> R) -> CommandBuffer<R> {
            use CommandBuffer::*;
            match buff {
                Sequential(v) => Sequential(v.into_iter().map(|c| helper(c, mapping_fn)).collect()),
                Parallel(v) => Parallel(v.into_iter().map(|c| helper(c, mapping_fn)).collect()),
                Single(x) => Single(Box::new(mapping_fn(*x))),
            }
        }
        
        helper(self, &mapping_fn)
    }
}
```

Full working sample on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f6de8690e2a983769122be7d8e289c2).